# 1 instance of the Kafka Consumer stops consuming from the topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

We have implemented the spring-kafka version 2.1.4.
We have 2 instances of the kafkalistener. Both the pods run smoothly but after a certain amount of time one of the instance of the listener stops listening to the messages from the topic.
Messages are being processed only by one Microservice instead of 2. It seems that the pod is still subscribed to the topic partition but it is not consuming the messages. Enable auto commit =false, we are manually committing the messages.
The max poll record is set to 500, the auto commit interval is set to 100, the session timeout is 30000 and the poll timeout is 10000.
Is there any issue with the configuration?

Comment: Could you provide a minimum code example that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: hi, i am using the @kafkaListener annotation for the consumer and using the topicpattern . @KafkaListener(topicPattern = "${topic.pattern}" ). Apart from this the configurations are done at the server startup and the configurations are mentioned above in the question.

Comment: These types of problems are usually that the consumer thread is "stuck" somewhere in user code, either the listener itself or some code called from it. Take a thread dump to see what the container thread(s) are doing. Also, debug logging will show polling activity.